# Updating list of string to a model property

Tags: c#, list, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I have this class:

```
public class Soup
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SoupName { get; set; }
    // other properties
}
```

I have a view that enables bulk update of the SoupName property. The IActionResult in my Controller correctly receives the modified values:

```
public IActionResult QuickEdit(List<string> soups)
{
    var soupNames = _soupRepository.AllSoups.Select(s => s.SoupName).ToList();

    for (var i = 0; i < soupNames.Count; i++)
    {
        soupNames[i] = soups[i];
    }

    _soupRepository.UpdateSoupNames(soups);
    return View(soups);
}
```

But I am stuck with the UpdateSoupNames method, I don't know how to update only the SoupNames of my Soup object. I have tried several things but when I call _appDbContext.SaveChanges(); nothing gets saved or updated. The soups being passed through are the updated ones. I just can't make it save correctly to my db. Below the latest thing I've tried:

```
    public void UpdateSoupNames(List<string> soups)
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < soups.Count; i++)
        {
            _appDbContext.Soups.Where(c => c.Id == i).ToList().Select(s => { s.SoupName = soups[i]; return s; });                      
        }
        _appDbContext.SaveChanges();

    }
```

So the question is, how do update and save the string values that are being passed through as a list of strings. I need to update and save all the modified values on my SoupName property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what your trying to do in this method below? You get soupNames and update them, but then don't use the result?

```
public IActionResult QuickEdit(List<string> soups)
{
    var soupNames = _soupRepository.AllSoups.Select(s => s.SoupName).ToList();

    for (var i = 0; i < soupNames.Count; i++)
    {
        soupNames[i] = soups[i];
    }

    _soupRepository.UpdateSoupNames(soups);
    return View(soups);
}
```

Best practice would be to pass the full model (with id) to the controller, if you wanted to just 'patch' soup name the model would only have the name in it. However in the interest of minimal change, I would update this to do the following:

```
public IActionResult QuickEdit(List<string> soups)
{
    var models = _soupRepository.AllSoups.ToList();

    for (var i = 0; i < soupNames.Count; i++)
    {
        models[i].SoupName = soups[i];
    }

    _soupRepository.UpdateSoupNames(models);
    return View(soups);
}
```

Passing the full model to your Repository will make the Repository method more re-usable and as I said above, it would be better if you passed the Id's along with the names.

Comment: Your way makes a lot of sense. I've implemented it and change my UpdateSoupMethod to the the snippet below and now it works:

        public void UpdateSoupNames(List<Soup> models)
        {
            _appDbContext.Soups.UpdateRange(models);
            _appDbContext.SaveChanges();

        }

Answer (score 0):

`.Select(s => { s.SoupName = soups[i]; return s; })` returns the entity but you aren't updating it in the underlying `DbContext`.

Also, your `Where(c => c.Id == i)` is filtering by id, so it should only return one entity, right? Try it like this:

```
public void UpdateSoupNames(List<string> soups)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < soups.Count; i++)
    {
        //this call actually updates the entity object in the underlying `DbContext`
        _appDbContext.Soups.Single(c => c.Id == i).SoupName = soups[i];
    }
    _appDbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

I can't actually test this code right now, so give it a try yourself.

On another note: your for loop on the action method doesn't seem to be necessary.